# Ionic 2 - Icon in alert

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I would like add icon in my Alert Message but it seems to disappear after building.

Here's the code:

```
openAppointmentPop(){
    let appointmentpop = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Rendez-vous',
        message: `
            <p><ion-icon ios="ios-calendar" md="md-calendar"></ion-icon> 26 février 2016</p>
            <p><ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon> 52, rue des Paquerette</p>

            `,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Modifier',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Disagree clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Retour',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Agree clicked');
        }
      }
    ]           
    });
    appointmentpop.present();
}
```

And the result:

```
<div class="alert-message" id="alert-msg-0">
    <p> 26 février 2016</p>
    <p> 52, rue des Paquerette</p>    
</div>
```

I really don't know how to proceed to get what I want.
Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to consider creating a modal instead of an alert

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
  private _htmlProperty: string = "<p><span name=\"alarm\" style=\"display:inline-block;font-family:Ionicons;\" class=\"icon icon-md ion-md-alarm\"></span> 26 février 2016</p><p><div name=\"pin\" style=\"display:inline-block;font-family:Ionicons;\" class=\"icon icon-md ion-md-alarm\"></div> 52, rue des Paquerette</p>";

  public htmlProperty() {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._htmlProperty);
  }

  openAppointmentPop() {
    let appointmentpop = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Rendez-vous',
      message: <any> this.htmlProperty(),
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Modifier',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Disagree clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Retour',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Agree clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    appointmentpop.present();
  }
```

Somehow ionic/angular tag  is not working in **_htmlproperty** so we need to use plan html tags and css classes.

**Second Option:** You could make your own custom popup as  suggested [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/10).

Comment: I'll take a look ! Thank you for the answere (:

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Ionic2 doesn't support icons in alerts.

There is a feature request on their Github repo: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7874

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.. Will need to do it by myself, thank's!

Answer (score 0):

I have **the solution**. It works perfectly on Ionic v3, but should work on version 2 as well.
See the link below:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/icon-in-toast/113750/4

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.